# Starting a new Activity from Handler/Runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable, android-handler

I am new to handlers and runnables. My intention is to start a new `Activity` from a `Runnable`. The new activity shows up, but only for a second and then the program closes all together. I have no idea why, so any help would be appreciated.

```
Boolean handlerrun = true;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, newactivity.class);

protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            if (somevalue < 0) {
                handlerrun = false;
            }

            if (handlerrun) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1);
            }

            if (!handlerrun) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };

    if (handlerrun) {
        handler.postDelayed(r, 1);
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

The code works in terms of stopping the runnable. I've heard you can use the `handler.removeCallbacks()` method, but for some reason it doesn't work with my code. So, I used the `boolean handlerrun` to stop the `Runnable` from restarting. The activity also comes up, but the issue is that the entire program just closes. I know my code for activity 2 is fine.

Comment: For a start you should put that code inside onCreate(), not inside onResume() method

Comment: why you call super.onResume(); twice

Comment: Is your app crashing or simply closes with no error? If it is crashing, show the Exception log, please.

Comment: It closes without an error. Also, I didn't know I had to put it inside OnCreate(). I'll try that out and see what happens.

Comment: I tried putting it in OnCreate(). It makes no difference. Logcat is not giving me any error. Also, if I put startActivity(intent) outside of the Handler, the program no longer closes, so there is no doubt that there is a problem with the Handler.